# Activate layered navigation without Anchor in Categories

Tags: magento2, category

Is it possible to activate the layered navigation filtering when setting the anchor attribute to false?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the Magento OOTB, the only workaround I know of is to create a static block and use it inside a widget added in the 'Sidebar Main' container: [image]

But this means you will have fixed links/ filters and not a dynamic set of filters.